# Python regex format

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to match some strings using Pythons **re**-module, but cant get it done correctly. The strings i've to deal with look like this *(example)*:

```
XY_efgh_1234_0040_rev_2_1_NC_asdf
XY_abcd_1122Ae_1150_rev2_1_NC
XY_efgh_0124e_50_NC
asdf_1980_2234a_2
XY_abcd_5098_2270_2_1_NC
PC_bos_7659Ae_1450sp_rev_2_1_NC_GRAPH
```

The pattern there is not constant, it could vary to some point. This is important to me:

- Forget about the start of the string, up to the first numeric value. Thats not important, i don't need this, it should be stripped from any result.
- Then there are **always** four digits, they can be followed by alphabetical characters (up to three). I need this part, extracted.
- Then, after some underscore (there might be a minus in it, too), is another set of numeric values i need, it's **always** two to four *(...and might be followed by up to three alphabetical characters, too)* .
- Right after this section, seperated by further underscores, there **could be** further numeric values which are important and belong to the previous values. There might be alphabetical characters in it, too...
- The end of the string might contain something like *"NC"* and maybe further characters, is not important and should be stripped.

So, according to the previous example, this is what i need to work with:

```
('1234',   '0040_rev_2_1')
('1122Ae', '1150_rev2_1')
('0124e',  '50')
('1980',   '2234a_2')
('5098',   '2270_2_1')
('7659Ae', '1450sp_rev_2_1')
```

...I've never done such *if-and-ifnot* things in RegEx, it's driving me crazy. Here is what I've got so far, but it's not exactly what I need:

```
pattern     = re.compile(
              r"""
              ([0-9]{4}
              [A-Z]{0,3})
              [_-]{1,3}
              ([0-9]{2,4}
              [0-9A-Z_-]{0,16})
              """,
              re.IGNORECASE | 
              re.VERBOSE
              )

if re.search(pattern, string):
    print re.findall(pattern, string)
```

When I use this on the last mentioned Example, this is what I get:

```
[(u'7659Ae', u'1450sp_rev_2_1_NC_GR')]
```

...*almost* what I need - but I don't know how to exclude this `_NC_GR` at the end, and this simple method of limiting the characters by count is just not good.

Does anyone have a nice and working solution to this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me, the solution of Martijn doesn't work. So I give my solution.

Take attention to the fact that I don't use `re.IGNORECASE`
Hence, my regex is able to catch the end of
`PC_bos_7659Ae_1450sp_rev_2_1_nc_woof`
I don't know if it is really what you want in this case

```
inputtext = """XY_efgh_1234_0040_rev_2_1_NC_asdf
XY_abcd_1122Ae_1150_rev2_1_NC
XY_efgh_0124e_50_NC
asdf_1980_2234a_2
XY_abcd_5098_2270_2_1_NC
PC_bos_7659Ae_1450sp_rev_2_1_NC_GRAPH
PC_bos_7659Ae_1450sp_rev_2_1_nc_woof"""
print inputtext
```

.

```
import re

print """\n----------------------------------------
WANTED
('1234',   '0040_rev_2_1')
('1122Ae', '1150_rev2_1')
('0124e',  '50')
('1980',   '2234a_2')
('5098',   '2270_2_1')
('7659Ae', '1450sp_rev_2_1')"""
print '----------- eyquem ----------------------'
ri = re.compile('^\D+'
                '(\d{4}[a-zA-Z]{0,3})'
                '[_-]+'
                '(.+?)'
                '(?:[_-]+NC.*)?$',
                re.MULTILINE)

for match in ri.findall(inputtext):
    print match
    
print '----------- Martijn ----------------------'
ro     = re.compile(
              r"""
              ([0-9]{4}
              [A-Z]{0,3})
              [_-]{1,3}
              ([0-9]{2,4}
              [0-9A-Z_-]{0,16}?)
              (?:[-_]NC)?
              """,
              re.IGNORECASE | re.VERBOSE)

for match in ro.findall(inputtext):
    print match
```

result

```
----------------------------------------
WANTED
('1234',   '0040_rev_2_1')
('1122Ae', '1150_rev2_1')
('0124e',  '50')
('1980',   '2234a_2')
('5098',   '2270_2_1')
('7659Ae', '1450sp_rev_2_1')
----------- eyquem ----------------------
('1234', '0040_rev_2_1')
('1122Ae', '1150_rev2_1')
('0124e', '50')
('1980', '2234a_2')
('5098', '2270_2_1')
('7659Ae', '1450sp_rev_2_1')
('7659Ae', '1450sp_rev_2_1_nc_woof')
----------- Martijn ----------------------
('1234', '0040')
('1122Ae', '1150')
('0124e', '50')
('1980', '2234')
('5098', '2270')
('7659Ae', '1450')
('7659Ae', '1450')
```

My regex can be used on individual lines::

```
for s in inputtext.splitlines(True):
    print ri.match(s).groups()
```

same result

.

### EDIT

```
import re

inputtext = """XY_efgh_1234_0040_rev_2_1_NC_asdf
XY_abcd_1122Ae_1150_rev2_1_NC
XY_efgh_0124e_50_NC
XY_efgh_0228e_66-__NC
asdf_1980_2234a_2   
asdf_2999_133a
XY_abcd_5098_2270_2_1_NC
XY_abcd_6099_33370_2_1_NC
XY_abcd_6099_3370abcd_2_1_NC
PC_bos_7659Ae_1450sp_rev_2_1_NC_GRAPH
PC_bos_7659Ae_1450sp_rev_2_1___NC_GRAPH
PC_bos_7659Ae_1450sp_rev_2_1_nc_woof_NC
PC_bos_7659Ae_1450sp_rev_2_1_anc_woof_NC
PC_bos_7659Ae_1450sp_rev_2_1_abNC_woof_NC"""

print '----------- Martijn 2 ------------'
ruu     = re.compile(r"""
              ( [0-9]{4} [A-Z]{0,3} )
              [_-]{1,3}
              ( [0-9]{2,4} (?:[0-9A-Z_-](?!NC))* )
              """, re.IGNORECASE | re.VERBOSE)
for match in ruu.findall(inputtext):
    print match
print '----------- eyquem 2 ------------'
rii = re.compile('[_-]'
                '(\d{4}[A-Z]{0,3})'
                '[_-]{1,3}'
                '('
                  '(?=\d{2,4}[A-Z]{0,3}(?![\dA-Z]))'
                  '(?:[0-9A-Z_-]+?)'
                 ')'
                '(?:[-_]+NC.*)?'
                '(?![0-9A-Z_-])',
                re.IGNORECASE)
for m in rii.findall(inputtext):
    print m
```

result

```
----------- Martijn 2 ------------
('1234', '0040_rev_2_1')
('1122Ae', '1150_rev2_1')
('0124e', '50')
('0228e', '66-_')
('1980', '2234a_2')
('2999', '133a')
('5098', '2270_2_1')
('6099', '33370_2_1')
('6099', '3370abcd_2_1')
('7659Ae', '1450sp_rev_2_1')
('7659Ae', '1450sp_rev_2_1__')
('7659Ae', '1450sp_rev_2_1')
('7659Ae', '1450sp_rev_2_1_')
('7659Ae', '1450sp_rev_2_1_a')
----------- eyquem 2 ------------
('1234', '0040_rev_2_1')
('1122Ae', '1150_rev2_1')
('0124e', '50')
('0228e', '66')
('1980', '2234a_2')
('2999', '133a')
('5098', '2270_2_1')
('7659Ae', '1450sp_rev_2_1')
('7659Ae', '1450sp_rev_2_1')
('7659Ae', '1450sp_rev_2_1')
('7659Ae', '1450sp_rev_2_1_anc_woof')
('7659Ae', '1450sp_rev_2_1_abNC_woof')
```

Remarks:

- my regex doesn't catch '33370_2_1' nor '3370abcd_2_1' because they don't respect the pattern "2 to 4 letters possibly followed by max 3 digits"
  whereas Martijn's solution catches them
- the ends of the portions catched by my regex are clean; in Martijn's code they aren't
- Martijn's regex stops in front of every sequence NC or nc, even if it isn't preceded by an underscore, that is to say even when these sequences are letters being part part of the wanted portion.
  If this characteristic of my regex isn't desired, say to me, I will modify it

Comment: Hi, thank you for your effort - but your regex isn't really what i was looking for. I really have no need for "nc_woof" or such things ;-) Btw, Martijns regex above is a little different to the one you use in your code - it leads to different results. Thank you anyway!

Comment: I don't understand what you man by _"no need for "nc_woof" or such things"_. I remark there are only digits at the end of the portion you want, separated from NC with _ or touching the end of the string when there is no NC. Do you mean that the case where letters at the end of this searched portion doesn't occur in your data ?

Comment: Also, you've put ``[_-]{1,3}`` in your code. Could these cases happen : ``PC_bos_7659Ae_1450sp_rev_2_1___NC_GRAPH`` or ``PC_bos_7659Ae_1450sp_rev_2_1_--NC_GRAPH`` ?

Comment: One of your results is `'1450sp_rev_2_1_nc_woof'`- that's containing the nc...-part at the end which i need be excluded from the match. I can't say where exactly case-sensitivity is important, but to be safe i'd like to match all alphabetical characters case-insensitive, that way i won't get into trouble when the data is not consistent. And while most of the data got its values seperated by underscores like `value_value`, some of the data could be seperated by this: `value_-_value` - that's why i wrote it like this.

Comment: I crafted my regex precisely to catch an ending ``_nc_woof`` , imagining that could be what you would like in such a case. But as I said, it was just hypothesis, and it was to show the danger of using re.IGNORECASE. Now my regex can be easily changed. But I'd like to understand thoroughly: may the case ``_2_nc_woof`` be possible and in this case ``nc`` having to be considered as ``NC`` ? Or is ``_NC`` the only (=cased) portion that signals the end of the portion you want to catch ?

Comment: Additionally, in case of a string ``PC_bos_7659Ae_1450sp_rev_2_1___NC_GRAPH`` , Martijn's regex will catch ``'1450sp_rev_2_1__'`` wheras mine will catch ``'1450sp_rev_2_1'``

Comment: Moreover, ``(?:[0-9A-Z_-](?!NC))*`` is ugly. It means : 0,1 or repetition of a character that must be a **character belonging to the set [0-9A-Z_-] not followed by NC**. That is to say, the regex motor will verify, for each character of the string that it progressively examines, that the character isn't followed by NC. That's equivalent in its effect, but not the same in the functionning as ``(?:[0-9A-Z_-]*?)(?!NC)``, the regex motor doesn't run in the same manner through the string, as far as I understand its business.

Comment: Hm. Okay - i don't know how the regex engine internally works, so i couldn't say anything about the "better" way to do this. But i see the limitations you point out, like: `PC_bos_7659Ae_1450sp_rev_2_1___NC -> 1450sp_rev_2_1__`. I could live with that, if needed - but the ending underscores are not part of the section i need. This means: ANY ending `_nc`, `_NC` or variations like `_-_nc` or `___NC`, both lower- and uppercase and following up to three characters of `[_-]`, should **not** match the result.

Comment: OK, I will see that. Just one thing I still don't understand : _following up to three characters of [_-]_ : do you mean after NC or nc , or if it's the end when there is neither nc nor NC ?

Comment: Oh, the difficulties of not being a native english speaker...  :-)

Comment: Another try to make that more clear: `nc` **or** `NC` is following this: `[_-]{1,3}`- that part, and everything following it, sould be excluded from the result. On this example: `PC_bos_7659Ae_1450sp_rev_2_1___NC_GRAPH`, this are the two parts i actually do need, first: `7659Ae`and second: `1450sp_rev_2_1`. Any unhderscore or dash **after** this second match is not part of the data i need.

Comment: If there is no such `NC` or `nc` -thing at all, the data contains no underscores or dashes at the end. Without this nc-thingy, the previous example would look like this: `PC_bos_7659Ae_1450sp_rev_2_1` - in that case, the second needed part reaches the end of the string. There is **no** data looking like this: `PC_bos_7659Ae_1450sp_rev_2_1___` - that just don't happen. I'm very sorry if you have trouble understanding me... i try my very best here :-)

Comment: That's me who have to be sorry not understand english very well. I search a lot of words on thefreedictionary.com or with Google's translator, but verbs with all these addons "for", "after","forth","up","down" etc, are the nightmare of non-anglophones.

Comment: But besides some language problems, you gave me a very well working solution! This regex in your edit leads to nice results, i can use them exactly as they are - thank you very much! I just have to pick this one as my accepted answer :-)

Answer (score 3):

You need to use a negative lookahead to match characters that are *not* followed by `NC`. Reformatting your regular expression a little to show of the groupings:

```
pattern     = re.compile(r"""
              ( [0-9]{4} [A-Z]{0,3} )
              [_-]{1,3}
              ( [0-9]{2,4} (?:[0-9A-Z_-](?!NC))* )
              """, re.IGNORECASE | re.VERBOSE)
```

with the `{0,16}` replaced with a bold `*` quantifier, results in:

```
>>> for match in pattern.findall(inputtext):
...     print match
... 
('1234', '0040_rev_2_1')
('1122Ae', '1150_rev2_1')
('0124e', '50')
('1980', '2234a_2')
('5098', '2270_2_1')
('7659Ae', '1450sp_rev_2_1')
```

So the (non-capturing) group `(?:[0-9A-Z_-](?!NC))` matches any digit, letter, underscore or dash that is not followed by the characters `NC`.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly what i was looking for - works perfect! I wasn't able to use this lookahead as described in the docs, thank you for this solution!

Comment: While this is working really good, the regex **eyquem** provided does a little different job when it comes to the end-recognition of the second part, the `_NC`-thingy. That difference makes his regex more usable for my needs. Thank you anyway!